# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, exception, ef-database-first

I am using Entity Framework 6.1.3 database first approach and an exception

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An error occurred while starting a transaction on the provider connection. See the inner exception for details.

is thrown on  this line

```
isAdded = entity.InsertMessage("", "0:1:1", 1, 1, 1, true);
```

This is the method definition generated by the edmx file with the stored procedure:

```
public virtual int InsertMessage(string message, string minuteThreshold, Nullable<int> accountId, Nullable<int> lOBId, Nullable<int> userId, Nullable<bool> isActive)
{
    var messageParameter = message != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("Message", message) :
            new ObjectParameter("Message", typeof(string));

    var minuteThresholdParameter = minuteThreshold != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("MinuteThreshold", minuteThreshold) :
            new ObjectParameter("MinuteThreshold", typeof(string));

    var accountIdParameter = accountId.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("AccountId", accountId) :
            new ObjectParameter("AccountId", typeof(int));

    var lOBIdParameter = lOBId.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("LOBId", lOBId) :
            new ObjectParameter("LOBId", typeof(int));

    var userIdParameter = userId.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("UserId", userId) :
            new ObjectParameter("UserId", typeof(int));

    var isActiveParameter = isActive.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("IsActive", isActive) :
            new ObjectParameter("IsActive", typeof(bool));

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("InsertInstructionalMessage", messageParameter, minuteThresholdParameter, accountIdParameter, lOBIdParameter, userIdParameter, isActiveParameter); // The exception is thrown here
}
```

This is the inner exception

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>
> New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session

If you need more info please ask as I don't have any clue whats causing this.

Comment: That's not a SqlException. It was thrown by EF, not SQL Server. Did you try to use the same context from multiple threads? Why? A context like a connection shouldn't be kept around. You *don't* gain any performance advantage but you *can* get creeping transactions, escalating locks and increased blocking

Comment: Are you using a singleton instance of the context perhaps? A static value or something returned by dependency injection?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos let me try to not do that assuming that I understood your comment.

Comment: I tried adding the context in my action method and it works now, though i don't know why.

Comment: Solution was to add the instantiation of the context class in each action method and not in the class level as a class property. Panagiotis was  correct in his assumption.